# how to check child table all column values are negative in sql

Tags: sql

Example :

table  A

```
id
1
2
3
```

table  B

```
id        value     fk_a
1          -5        1
2          -7        1
3           5        2
4          -10       3
5          20        3
```

table A  --> id 1   Have all child table column (value) negative

Comment: Edit the question add sample output.

Comment: please post data as text not as image

Comment: Thank you, consider adding expected output also

Comment: He said *"table A --> id 1 Have all child table column (value) negative"*. The expected output is 1

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ALL`

**Valid query for PostgreSQL and Oracle**

```
 select * from A
 where id = ALL (select fk_a from B where value < 0 and fk_a = id)

 select * from A
 where id <> ALL (select fk_a from B where `value` > 0 and fk_a = A.id)
```

**Valid Query for MySQL**

```
select * from A
where id <> ALL (select fk_a from B where `value` > 0 and fk_a = A.id)
```

[Working Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8AEkZFcLFH1t3gAncUFJKj/0)

Comment: This fetch all rows from A [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kNcF68LQwajBeRzqj16gBq/1)

Comment: can you check my fiddle please

Comment: It looks like environment related issue, It is working on Oracle and PostgreSQL

Comment: @Simonare about to say the same.

Comment: I am surprised about how MYSQL behaves, I will check reference docs for more information

Comment: MySQL is always surprising. In the past, 31/02/<any year> was a **valid** date.

Comment: Eh, At least It is not surprising that much right now :) I added MySQL version of it as well. You can check if you want

Answer (score 1):

I would use a sub-query get the FK ids of the entries that has positives values, and then use the result of that query to filter in the main query using a `WHERE NOT IN` clause

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO A
  (`id`)
VALUES
  (1),
  (2),
  (3);

CREATE TABLE B (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `value` INTEGER,
  `fk_a` INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_a) REFERENCES A (id)
);

INSERT INTO B
  (`id`, `value`, `fk_a`)
VALUES
  (1, -5, 1),
  (2, -7, 1),
  (3, 5, 2),
  (4, -10, 3),
  (5, 20, 3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.id NOT IN
(
  SELECT tb.fk_a
  FROM B tb
  WHERE tb.`value` >= 0
);
```

**Output**

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6oZbxQhorcyhFMVorZkUSR/2)

Comment: this Query give me accurate  Result ,

Comment: This query is for MySQL, check Simonare's answer too

Comment: Hi  Cid ,  I Cross Check your and Simonare Query , I got two different Result and Finally i got some difference value in table B column value that is 0E-9 (0.00E+00)  , your query Consider that +v value  and Simonare Query Consider that -v value , that's why Simonare query give Unexpected result

Comment: @TusharGodase use `>= 0` in his query to remove the zeros